# Bash - sometimes creates only empty output

Tags: bash, output

I am trying to create a bash dictionary script that accepts first argument and creates file named after that, then script accepts next arguments (which are files inside same folder) and outputs their content into file (first argument). It also sorts, deletes symbols etc., but main problem is, that sometimes ouptut file is empty (I am passing one non empty file and one non existing file), after deleting and running script few more times it is sometimes empty sometimes not.

```
#!/bin/bash

numberoffileargs=$(( $# - 1 ))
exitstat=0
counterexit=0
acceptingstdin=0;
> "$1";
#check if we have given input files given
if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    #for cycle going through input files
    for i in "${@:2}"
        do
    #check whether input file is readable
            if [ -r "${i}" ]; then
                cat "${i}" >> "$1"      
    #else redirect to standard output
            else
            exitstat=2
            counterexit=$((counterexit + 1))
            echo "file does not exist" 1>&2
            fi
       done 
else
    echo "stdin code to be done"
    acceptingstdin=1
        #stdin input to output file
#stdin=$(cat)
fi
    #one word for each line, alphabetical sort, alphabet only, remove duplicates
#all lowercase
#sort -u >> "$1"



if [ "$counterexit" -eq "$numberoffileargs" ] && [ "$acceptingstdin" -eq 0 ]; then 
    exitstat=3
fi
cat "$1" | sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z\-]+/ /g' | tr A-Z a-z | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | sed '/^$/d'     > "$1"
echo "$numberoffileargs"
echo "$counterexit"
echo "$exitstat"
exit  $exitstat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your script with some syntax improvement. Your trouble came from the fact that the dictionary was both on input and output on your pipeline; I added a temp file to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

(($# >= 1)) || { echo "Usage: $0 dictionary file ..." >&2 ; exit 1;}
dict="$1"
shift

echo "Creating $dict ..."
>| "$dict" || { echo "Failed." >&2 ; exit 1;}

numberoffileargs=$#
exitstat=0
counterexit=0
acceptingstdin=0

if (($# > 0)); then
    for i ; do
        #check whether input file is readable
        if [ -r "${i}" ]; then
            cat "${i}" >> "$dict"
        else
            exitstat=2
            let counterexit++
            echo "file does not exist" >&2
        fi
    done 
else
    echo "stdin code to be done"
    acceptingstdin=1
fi

if ((counterexit == numberoffileargs && acceptingstdin == 0)); then 
    exitstat=3
fi

sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z\-]+/ /g' < "$dict" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr ' ' '\n' | 
sort -u | sed '/^$/d' >| tmp$$

mv -f tmp$$ "$dict"

echo "$numberoffileargs"
echo "$counterexit"
echo "$exitstat"
exit  $exitstat
```

The pipeline might be improved.

Comment: Not sure why, but terminal says "Line 19 - directory or file doesn't exist", redirect should create it, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess.